Demodulate FSK (Bell 103) with discriminator, downsample to reduce delay?
First, let me preface this by mentioning the excellent answer from Dan Boschen in this post:
Decoding a PCM BFSK signal (Bell 103)
In a distant past I was part of a project where we demodulated and decoded B103 FSK on a microcontroller using a "delay and multiply frequency discriminator" similar to what was outlined in the above mentioned post. However, in that project the sample frequency was adjusted to 4680 Hz (right at the input ADC), which makes the required delay be exactly 1 sample (and the following low pass FIR filter was order 9). However, if the sample frequency is fixed at 8 kHz, the number of samples to delay becomes 19 (again, as described in Dan's post), which is somewhat problematic at a bit rate of 300 bps.
I am now going to redo this, but this time the sample frequency is fixed at 8 kHz. I've played around a bit with Octave (being a complete novice), and it seems to me that if I downsample my input from 8000 to 4680 Hz, I can replicate the results from the old implementation, which handles 300 bps fine. Using 8 kHz and a delay of 19 samples provides very little margin, since the bit time is ~26 samples at 300  bps.
My question is basically if I am overlooking something essential here. It seems somewhat counterintuitive to downsample the input to make the demodulation more responsive (for lack of a better word), but I believe that to be the case in this particular scenario.
As a side note, I am of course aware that there are other (and more accurate) ways of doing the demodulation, but given that the simple frequency discriminator method has worked in the past, I am inclined to go that route again.

I don't see an issue with resampling to 4680 other than the resources needed to do that properly (compared to alternate approaches such as what I showed could be implemented directly at 8KHz). If you're not concerned with minimizing resources and it works, then no harm done --- you can move on to other fun things.

Hi mroek, let's assume a entry-level microcontroller of the last ~20 years as baseline, then we're talking about a Cortex-M0+ running at 24 MHz. These things typically do a fixed-point multiplication in a single cycle, same for addition. So, if we're dealing with 8000 samples a second, then we still have 1500 multiplications and additions we can do per sample (of course, completely ignoring memory bw, irq, data mov); that's a lot of filter you can run on the signal before the next sample is there.

So, even if you do the 8000 -> 4680 (that's 200->117) resampling in a very nice filter with a very naive implementation, that should work :)

Thanks for your comments. I'll play around a bit more, and see where I end up. I am very far from a signal processing expert, but I still want to be able to understand whatever solution I end up with, and this particular one at least fits that bill.
Yes, the resampling indeed works out to 200->117, and I have already implemented a very simple resampler that appears to work in this context.

Resampling "nicely"

My question is basically if I am overlooking something essential here.

Not really – resampling to meet the symbol clock is something very routinely done in receiver systems.
Now, admittedly, your resampling ratio of 117/200 is a tiny bit annoyingly "odd", but still, this would be doable (as a classical rational resampler with a polyphase filter bank, so that you can work at 8000/200 Hz instead of 8000·117 Hz) on a entry-level to mid-range microcontroller. Remember that your resampling filter doesn't have to be very sharp; your signal bandwidth inherently stays small even compared to the output sampling rate.
The "usual" way to tackle "small and odd" resampling ratios such as 117/200 in firmware is not to go the rational resampling route with large decimation and interpolation factors. First, you'd bring the input sampling rate to be close to the output sampling rate. In your case, that's easy, halfband filter decimating by 1/2 gives you 4000 Hz. So, you're left with a resampling by a factor of 1.17.

Then you just go ahead and do an arbitrary resampler. Idea here would be to keep a set of $N$ filters (say, $N=8$) around, the first having $0/N$ sample delay, the second having $1/N$ delay, and so on. These filters don't have to be long! Your resampling algorithm then just needs to track which delay is closest to what is needed for each output sample, and just copy the right output sample from the right delay "branch" to the output.
For example, we have a resampling ratio of 1.17 (interpolation); so each output sample is $1/1.17 \approx 0.8547$ input samples apart.



output sample index
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
…




input sample delay
0
0.85
1.70
2.56
3.41
4.27
5.13
5.98
…


integer input sample
0
0
1
2
3
4
5
5+1
…


fractional sample
0
0.85
0.7
0.56
0.41
0.27
0.13
0.98
…


closest n/8 delay
0
7
6
5
3
2
1
8
…



So you pick the zeroth (counting from 0) filter's output, then the 7. filter's  of that same sample period, then you let one input sample "percolate" through all 8 filters, take the output from the 6. filter, then process one input sample, take the output from the 5. filter, process one input sample, take the output from the 3. filter, process one input sample, take the output from the 2. filter, process one sample, take the output from the 1. filter, process directly take the output from the 0. filter (because 8 mod 8 = 0, but it's still the next sample)¹.
Takeaway is that you calculate the sample you need
Why the effort? Simply because you run exactly into the problem you've run into in modern receivers: Your receiver symbol clock simply isn't exactly the transmitter symbol clock. You'd want to build a control loop that looks at your symbol detector and says "hm, this looks like we're a bit faster than the transmitter, can we reduce the resampling ratio a bit?", for example. Now, with the ability to compute a good approximation to the "true" resampled signal with different delays for each sample, you get the freedom to build that loop – "smoothly", without having to drop samples at some point or invent them out of nowhere, i.e., without suddenly breaking all locking onto the transmitter's signal that used to work before
Without Resampling "nicely"
I don't know Bell 103 beyond its mark and space frequencies. I bet it has some simple framing, so the receive knows where the first bit starts. And I bet frames (or however they were called) were of finite length.
And if you have, say, 1% of resampling error, but your frame is say, only 10 symbols long, then, oh well, you're off by 10% of a symbol by the end of the frame, which is not a problem in 2-FSK like yours. For example, if Bell 103 has only short periods of time between synchronization points, you can resample to 4800 instead of 4680 Hz and "act as if it actually was 4680". Resampling by 3/5 is by all means pretty cheap.
But, as suggested, I'd just stick with Dan's first approach – I don't really see why it would fail for 8 kHz sampling rate, it seems to me to be trivial to compute even for the cheapest of microcontrollers with an ADC, and frankly, at the human and computational effort you spend on resampling, you'd get at most the same bit error performance as with optimal frequency discriminator bounds. So, the easiest solution here is also the best: center between space and mark, decimate to just a small factor above symbol rate with cheap real-valued half-band filters (few coefficients, high coefficient reuse: excellent for MCUs with limited register banks!), and then do a frequency discrimination.
In educational material I sometimes showed multiple ways to demodulate 2-FSK: one with a simple inverse tan approximation and a threshold, one based on the magnitude of two bandpass filters and a decision based on who has more output power, one based on summing powers from a full FFT and finally Goertzel, just to then make a walk to PLLs through "but what if we're off in frequency"?
Dan's approach that directly works on 8 kHz samples is better than all the above, as it deals with large frequency offsets gracefully, inherently, and nearly for free.

¹ Of course, you are quantizing the delay here to 1/8 of an output sample period. And that means you get jitter, and reduce your signal quality. In your use case, not much of a problem, but if you wanted to improve that, you'd use both more than 8 filters, and interpolate (linearly, quadratically, or approximately sinc shaped, depending on how much compute you want to pay for your signal quality) between adjacent delays.

+1 for nice answer and simple approach for resampling appropriate for this waveform. It is worth mentioning in case anyone considers resampling this way for other waveforms where higher SNR (or equivalently low EVM) is needed that nearest neighbor is equivalent to using only a Sinc filter as the resampling filter (resulting in error from aliasing in the decimation and poor rejection of the up sampling images). For those cases a polyphase resampling filter would be a good choice assuming the 117N coefficients for a low order FIR (I guess 4 to 5 taps would be plenty) can be stored in memory.

Thank you for taking the time to do that writeup! Appreciated.
As mentioned in a comment further up, I have already made a resampler that does pretty much what you outlined. My resampler interpolates between the two values where my output sample should be (and on every 200th sample it lines up exactly, of course), and generally seems to work.

I will also review again Dan's first approach, but I am not sure I can properly understand how it actually works, my signal processing knowledge is quite limited. I might be able to take the contents from that post and make it work in my application, but I wouldn't really understand it, which would not be very satisfying.
Let me be clear, there is nothing wrong with his explanation, it is my lack of understanding that is the problem.
I will flag this answer as a solution, as my original question has been answered.

@mroek your resampler is the special case of the arbitrary resampler I describe, with $N=1$ and linear interpolation as in the footnote :) I think once you get the hang of it, you'll find Dan's approach to be much easier conceptionally than resampling :) you've actually entered the DSP pool at the deep end. Note that we really like you asking questions – also about approaches in answers!

And to add for completeness interpolating between the two closest samples is identical to using a Sinc squared filter, or cascade of two moving averages (also not suitable for higher order wideband waveforms but perfectly fine for this application )
